# synchronization of singleton state

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized, concurrenthashmap

I've got this singleton. As I made it `enum` it's thread safe for `getInstance`.

```
public enum ExtensionRegistry {
    REGISTRY;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExtensionRegistry.class);

    // key is a class name
    private Map<String, Plugin> extensions = new HashMap<>();

    public void registerPlugin(Plugin plugin) {
        LOGGER.info("Register plugin: [{}].", plugin);
        extensions.put(plugin.getId(), plugin);
    }

    public Plugin getPlugin(String id) {
        return extensions.get(id);
    }

    public List<String> listAvailablePlugins() {
        return extensions.values().stream()
                .map(Plugin::getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public IPluggable getRegisteredClass(String id) {
        Plugin plugin = extensions.get(id);

        if (null == plugin) {
            LOGGER.debug("No class with id [{}] found in the registry!", id);
            return null;
        } else {
            IPluggable instance = null;
            try {
                instance = (IPluggable) Class.forName(plugin.getId()).newInstance(); // should exist!
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                LOGGER.error("Failed to create instance of class with id [{]].", id, exc);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

What else should I change/synchronize in order to make it truly thread safe? Use `ConcurrentHashMap`? Add `synchronized` for each method?

Comment: Synchronize the public methods. `HashMap` isn't thread-safe; you need exclusive access to it in all these methods.

Comment: @AndyTurner but if I make it `ConcurrentHashMap` it won't help? Because for example for `registerPlugin` method making it synchronized make no sense I think as it has only one action

Comment: The number of actions is irrelevant. The number of threads performing the action is relevant. Unsynchronized, unguarded by a lock, lacking a concurrent structure, those multiple accesses to `plugin` and the method that returns it are doomed in a concurrent context.

Comment: Then when I need `ConcurrentHashMap`? Because as far as I understand I can leave `HashMap` there

Comment: Never allow two threads to write to the same HashMap at the same time, never let on thread write while another reads from a HashMap. If any of those two can occur, use a ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: How often do you poll the registry? How many threads are expected to access it at the same time? To me, it looks like making all methods `synchronized` and not changing anything else is the simplest solution. Using a `ConcurrentHashMap` correctly can be more complicated and as long as you don’t experience performance or liveness problems, there is no reason to make it complicated.

Comment: @Holger only 2 - 3

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I'd definitely use a ConcurrentMap implementation. Remember to use the concurrent methods when you're making sequential calls to check and alter the Map.

Concurrency is hard. And even if you get it right, someone else can easily come along later and screw it up. Using classes written by experts can go a long to getting it right and more maintainable.

In this code, you can still have race conditions as the set and get are exposed through your methods. The Map will be safe, but there's no guarantee that you'll get what you expect when calling get(). Someone else can call set() right after you do, and then your get() will return "their" value. You're allowing the overwriting of values in registerPlugin. If you have to have that, then there's little way around this condition. If you can lose that, then using putIfAbsent() can help you.

---(removed inappropriate code) ---

Comment: So I have to use `ConcurrentHashMap` with synchronized `listAvailablePlugins` and `getRegisteredClass`?

Comment: With ConcurrentHashMap you don't need to synchronize (in this example). Synchronize has generally fallen out of favor, as it's difficult to use correctly and efficiently. The Lock family of classes in util.concurrent are generally preferred.

Comment: As far as I know `lock` are preferrable as they allow to unlock (unlike intrinsic locks aka `synchronized`) and set timeouts as far as I remember..So If I change to `ConcurrentHashMap` I won't need to `synchronized` any method at all?

Comment: You'll need to manage the lock(s) yourself. ConMap does it internally for you.